# How to make restsharp to work with the right encoding for response?

Tags: encoding, restsharp

I have the same problem like this question
[RestSharp ignores response charset encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37720731/restsharp-ignores-response-charset-encoding/45788604#45788604).

But there is no right answer!
Code like this

```
IRestResponse RSP = client.Execute(request);
```

not like this

```
Encoding encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
var result = encoding.GetString(response.RawBytes);
```

It means the resetsharp must deserializ the result with right encoding.
Someone can help?

Answer (score -1):

I solved this problem by myshelf

you just down the code source from github and edit the code

stemp 1： find HttpResponse.cs ：
stemp 2: find Http.cs ,
Ohm,maybe this solution is not match you，my request result like this,just edit the code like what I do ,then it will work well
[enter image description here][3]